# Sum of float numbers in a list in Python

Tags: python, sum, nltk

I have got float values  in `s`:

```
p = list(swn.senti_synsets(a))
s = p[0].pos_score()
print(s)

# Output
0.0
0.0
1.0
0.0
0.25
0.25
```

then I tried, `print(sum(s))`
which gives the error 'float' object is not Iterable. 
how to do this ?

Solution: 
Strange that I found the answer myself, i dont know but putting the thing of a separate function worked. `

```
for x in token: 
sum_pos=sum_pos+posCheck(x) 
sum_neg=sum_neg+negCheck(x) 
def posCheck(a): 
p=list(swn.senti_synsets(a)) 
s = p[0].pos_score() return(s)`

def negCheck(a): p=list(swn.senti_synsets(a)) s = p[0].neg_score() return(s)
```

I couldn't sum up the list, but when I put the function with returntype, it returned the sum of the positive numbers. Thanks to all of you for trying to help.

Answer (score 6):

To sum float from a list , one easy way is to use fsum

```
import math

l=[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25]
math.fsum(l)
```

Comment: For a long series of floats only `math.fsum` ensures the lowest float rounding error of the result.

Answer (score 3):

```
values = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25]

print sum(values)
```

works fine for me

Comment: its not this one, the values are not stored in a array.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
>>> l=[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25]
>>> sum(map(float,l))
1.5
```

---

As other said, `sum(l)` will also work. I don't know why you are getting error with that.

---

One possible reason might be that your list is of string data type. Convert it to float as:

```
l = map(float, l)
```

or

```
l = [float(i) for i in l]
```

Then using `sum(l)` would work properly.

---

EDIT: You can convert the `s` into list and then sum it.

```
s = p[0].pos_score()
print sum(list(s))
```

Comment: @SwarupRajbhandari try converting the list to float data type as `print sum(map(float,list(s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It adds all `pos_score()` to a list, and then prints the sum.

```
p = list(swn.senti_synsets(a))
s = [x for x in p[0].pos_score()]
print(sum(s))
```

Comment: this printed the corresponding sum of positive values rather. 0.5
0.375
1.125
0.0
0.25
0.25
2.125
0.125

Comment: i only wanted the sum of the positive numbers of the words at 0 position.

Comment: @SwarupRajbhandari what about now. Edited the code.

Comment: i am getting a feeling it is not possible, it didnt worked, same old problem, 'float' object not iterable

Comment: Well then it seems that there is only 1 pos_score() in p[0]

Comment: i think it is in float numbers, (because of the error it is giving) but its just not stored in a array, if it were, then the loop thing would work, have you tried running the code in your PC ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your original code, `s` is not iterable, and you can thus not use sum on a non-iterable object. If you were to add each value from `s` into a list, you could sum the list to give you the result you are looking for.

Not sure the function `pos_score()` function works, but perhaps you can create and return the list result from that function?

Answer (score 0):

```
def do(*args):
    mylist_ = [float("{:.2f}".format(num)) for num in args]
    result =(sum(mylist))
    return result

print(do(23.32,45,67,54.27))
```

Result:

```
189.59
```

I hope this will help.